# Problemas Con Hestia Cp, para conectarme remotamente a base de datos de mysql

Tags: php, aws

Hace poco estoy usando hestia cp, y todo va muy bien, tengo la base de datos montada, pero no logro conectarme desde un cliente externo.
ni tampoco desde codigo en php, ya habilite en el cortafuegos del servidor el puerto 3306, y en aws permiti todo el trafico y aun no funciona, Alguna solucion?

Comment: para conectarse remotamente que se coloca? la ip del servidor con el puerto 3306?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verán despues de mucho intentar muchas cosas, he encontrado en un foro una solución, y es debido a que mysql por defecto en las configuraciones en hestia cp, no permite conexiones que no provengan del localhost..

lo que se debe hacer es acceder mediante ssh a la vps, y reconfigurar el archivo

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

y cambiar el bind_address a 0.0.0.0, que quiere decir que todos puedes conectarse

Answer (score 1):

para poder conectarte a una DB de forma remota en HestiaCP es necesario que a parte de tener el puerto 3306 abierto, el usuario propietario de esa base de datos tenga permiso de acceso desde cualquier red (Osea, que tenga el atributo de conexión en **%**)

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de editar el fichero:

sudo nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

Recuerda abrir cortafuegos en el puerto 3306, tanto en hestiacp como een el cortafuegos del vps, en mi caso un oacle free tier.